# Is a tin-ear one who dislikes music or one who dislikes new popular music? Why?

Tags: expressions, idioms, slang

I know folks who couldn't hear well used to use a tin-ear to help but I don't understand the connection between a tin-ear and a dislike of music or of new popular music.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To describe someone as having a *tin ear* is to say that they lack accurate hearing or mental perception of sound and/or music. The sensitivity of someone with a *tin ear* is generally compared to any average or moderately talented person in music. (A moderate to very talented person might be described as having *an ear for music*.)

People who don't appreciate music or have poor taste in music are commonly said to have a *tin ear*. If a person dislikes music or dislikes popular music, they *can* be said to have *tin ear*, but that would probably be said in a scoffing way, given that it's a subjective opinion.

A person can be said to have a *tin ear for  music* and that would be the same as having a *tin ear*. One can also be described as having a tin ear for other things. A *[tin ear for politics](http://www.ft.com/intl/cms/s/0/d85e5ae8-bbb9-11e1-9aff-00144feabdc0.html#axzz2vndDhxAE)* means not sensitive or perceptive in politics.

Answer (score 6):

I've never heard *tin ear* used as a term applied to someone who "dislikes new music." I've often heard it used to mean someone is *tone deaf*, and I just checked several dictionaries that seem to back that. [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tin+ear) defines it as:

> an insensitivity to or inability to distinguish differences in musical sound.

So, having a tin ear doesn't mean someone dislikes music; in fact, quite the opposite may be true:

> Can you help me tune my guitar? I've got a tin ear.

That said, the [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=tin%20ear) defines the term as you say:

> 1. an inability to appreciate music
> 2. a person who does not appreciate music or has poor taste in music

However, I had trouble finding matching definitions in more reputable dictionaries. Moreover, even the UD definition is controversial: It has 4 thumbs-down votes along side a meager 6 thumbs-ups.

Still, if someone doesn't appreciate my favorite music group, or a favorite music genre, I can see how I might jokingly use the term as a gibe at their music tastes:

> You don't like U2? You must have a tin ear!

The Urban Dictionary often mentions more colloquial usages like that one.

Comment: People who are truly tone-deaf often cannot appreciate music.

Comment: @Peter - I suppose that means people who are truly tone deaf would be able appreciate some of today's newer music more than I can... ;^)

Answer (score 2):

As you correctly pointed out, a tin-ear or ear trumpet was used to amplify sound for people with hearing deficiencies.

In current usage, saying someone has a tin-ear means that they have bad hearing. And, in the context you're describing, it is a way of saying:  you must be hard of hearing, because *this* is good music!

This expression is also used for people who cannot learn to play music.  The logic being that they don't hear music well, and hence cannot learn to replicate it appropriately.